# Can't SSH into openssh server version 7.8 and greater

Tags: centos, ssh, openssh, sshd

I can't log into a clean Centos8 install on my VPS from the terminal using public key authentication.

When logging in it seems to authenticate OK, but then it times-out then returns a "Connection reset by [remote host ip address]" (not peer).

I've checked out all the logs. But nothing is really forthcoming.

Things I've checked out:

- /var/log/messages
- /var/log/audit/audit.log
- /var/log/secure
- Permissions for ~/.ssh and ~/.ssh/id_rsa* files
- /etc/ssh/sshd_config

I've tried logging in from different machines in my LAN without success:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- CentOS 7 machine
- WSL

It's worthwhile to note I have no problems logging into a clean CentOS7 install from the same VPS.

Is there a change in OpenSSH 8 that I'm not aware of?

I've attached verbose output for logging into a CentOS7 and CentOS8 system:

- CentOS 7 SSH OK: https://pastebin.com/uGc1T8tk
- CentOS 8 SSH Fail: https://pastebin.com/XadQQEBK

As you can see authentication succeeds in both:

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey)
```

The main difference I can see in CentOS 8 is that it's now using OpenSSH 8 instead of OpenSSH 7

Is there a change in OpenSSH 8 that I'm not aware of?

Thanks all in advance.

---

**Edit 1**

@thehostingadmin I don't know how to copy n paste from the web GUI but here's the output from the command you provided: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lJec.jpg

**Edit 2**

```
# sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle=0
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_recycle: No such file or directory

# sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse=0
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 0
```

Result: Still no dice

**Edit 3**

Success/Fail Matrix

```
|         OS         |  SSH Client   |   Network    | Auth |  Success   |
|--------------------|---------------|--------------|------|------------|
| Ubuntu 18.04 (WSL) | OpenSSH_7.6p1 | LAN (NAT x2) | OK   | E01 | TO/H |
| Debian 10 (RPi)    | OpenSSH_7.9p1 | LAN (NAT x2) | OK   | TO/H       |
| Ubuntu 18.04       | OpenSSH_7.6p1 | LAN (NAT x1) | OK   | E02        |
| CentOS 7.8         | OpenSSH_7.4p1 | LAN (NAT x1) | OK   | TO/H       |
| CentOS 7.8         | OpenSSH_7.4p1 | VPS          | OK   | OK         |
```

- `E01`: Connection reset by [remote host ip address] port 22
- `E02`: packet_write_wait: Connection to [remote host ip address] port 22: Broken pipe
- `TO/H`: Timeout/Hang

**Edit 4**
Made the following changes:

```
# /etc/ssh/sshd_config
TCPKeepAlive yes
ClientAliveInterval 20
ClientAliveCountMax 5
```

No measurable difference.

**Edit 5**

When ssh client throws error `E01`, I can see the following on the server:

```
# journalctl -u systemd-logind -fn0
Aug 27 14:51:18 host systemd-logind[701]: New session 136 of user root.
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype keepalive@openssh.com reply 1
Aug 27 14:51:38 host systemd-logind[701]: Session 136 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Aug 27 14:51:38 host systemd-logind[701]: Removed session 136.
```

A successful login looks like this:

```
Aug 27 15:04:42 host systemd-logind[701]: New session 143 of user root.
```

**Edit 6**

I turned `LogLevel` to `DEBUG3` and found the following in `/var/log/secure`

```
# Login Fail
Aug 27 15:59:07 host sshd[9387]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 124
Aug 27 15:59:26 host sshd[9389]: Read error from remote host <wan ip> port 2611: Connection reset by peer
Aug 27 15:59:26 host sshd[9389]: debug1: do_cleanup

# Login Success
Aug 27 15:57:48 host sshd[9360]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 124
```

**Edit 7**

Apologies to @fra-san. Adding more verbose logging (`-vvv`) did provide more detail

```
# SSH fail
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: send packet: type 1
Connection reset by <remote host ip> port 22

# SSH Success
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Activate the web console with: systemctl enable --now cockpit.socket
```

**Edit 8**

Switched out my home router (custom firmware) with ISP provided router. Still no joy.

**Edit 9**

Wading into wireshark packet tracing.

- Success vs Fail: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkL0z.jpg
- Graph: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWrog.jpg

Note: After raising my issue with my hosting provider (works for them) the OpenSSH server on the server has switched to OpenSSH 7.8 - but the issue persist.

**Edit 10**

Wireshark. Client vs Server: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRZRW.jpg

Notes

- Frame 29 from server not received by client
- Hosting provider changed `openssh` back to v8

Comment: This isn't really likely to help, but attaching more verbose debugging information (obtained using `ssh -vvv`) to your question may provide some hints.

Comment: Also, trying to rule out some kinds of issues: are you able to `ssh` to your CentOS 8 system by using a different authentication method?

Comment: Adding more verbose debug information didn't provide any more detail into the issue.

Comment: I can do password login only by using my VPS provider's web based console. Password login in any other way results in the password being requested again and again

Comment: Well that's quite peculiar. I'm feeling suspicious of your network connection. Are you able to attempt the SSH connection from a different host/network?

Comment: Surprisingly, I just managed to login (pubkey) from another host (outside my network). All the machines I've tried to date that have failed are behind double NAT if that makes any difference. Plus the output for journalctl is same for success and fail :|

Comment: Have you tried reaching out to your hosting provider to ask them to review the network config and verify that it's setup properly? @denormalizer ?

Comment: I recall a similar issue here a couple of years ago that turned out to be triggered by tcpkeepalive, the fix in that case was to turn that off in ssh configs.

Comment: @thehostingadmin I have reached out to them. But they're slow to respond

Comment: @user1998586 I think I've done that on the client side. But not on the server side. Might give it another go

Comment: @user1998586 Added TCPKeepAlive on the server. No measurable difference. See Edit 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some good news.

I raised an issue with my ISP. They've issued me with a new IP. I don't know what else they did but it has resolved the issue.

I have also raised an issue with redhat developers working on `openssh`.

They said this is a known issue especially in the VMWare community:

https://communities.vmware.com/thread/590825

The issue is related to a change in OpenSSH_7.8 relating to the `QoS` flag.

http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.8

The **workaround** is to use the following in your `~/.ssh/config` file

```
Host *
    IPQoS=throughput
```

I will not mark this as the answer until I can confirm it working on my end.

Comment: It seems my upstream router (ISP) had problems with the QoS changes made in openssh server 7.8. I was moved to a different router which fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to know without enabling DEBUG logging and then tailing sshd with journalctl on the VPS.

To do that you'll need to ask your VPS provider how to access the server via Console. Different providers have different methods.

Add the following configuration anywhere in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the VPS:

`LogLevel DEBUG`

Restart sshd on the VPS:

`sudo systemctl restart sshd`

Tail the sshd log on the VPS:

`journalctl -u sshd -fn0`

Now attempt to ssh from your local machine so that you can see what sshd says is wrong.

**EDIT**: Update based on results of comments:

Considering the fact that you're having difficulties connecting from hosts that NATd, check to see if the following kernel configs are enabled on your Cent 8 VPS, and if so disable them:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle=0

sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse=0
```

If this works use the `/etc/sysctl.conf` to persist those changes through a reboot.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I've updated my question with the output

Comment: @denormalizer I added a potential solution based on a common issue I've seen. Could you give it a shot and let us know if it works?

Comment: Thanks for following up. Please see Edit 2 (and Edit 3)

Answer (score 0):

This made the difference for me:

```
restorecon -Rv ~/.ssh
```

From here: https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/SecuringSSH

Comment: Permissions can sometimes be the source of these issues. But not in my case.